# Detect click on a blank item in a list control

Tags: c++, mfc, listcontrol

In my mfc dialog based application, there is a CListCtrl. I need to disable a button when the user clicks on an empty item in the list control.I used NM_CLICK message and achieved this. But if the user drags the mouse out of list control area and releases the mouse this doesn't work. I found the reason that NM_CLICK will be called only on receiving button up message.Is there any other solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for the issue. There is a message which can be handled if the user drags the mouse using left button namely [LVN_BEGINDRAG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/aa924485.aspx).By handling this message in the OnBeginDrag function I update the button status.So the button gets updated as soon as the user tries to drag the mouse.The code is as below:
In the header add

`afx_msg void OnBeginDrag( NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult );`

In the implementation add message map and corresponding function:

> BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP( .. )
>
> ON_NOTIFY( LVN_BEGINDRAG, IDC_LIST1, OnBeginDrag )
>
> END_MESSAGE_MAP
>
> OnBeginDrag( .... )
>
> {
>
> Updatebutton();
>
> }

It solves the issue. thank you all for the support.

Answer (score 1):

> But if the user drags the mouse out of list control area and releases the mouse this doesn't work.

That is entirely by design, and you shouldn't *want* those clicks to "count". This is the only way that a user has of changing her mind in the middle of a click. It works like this:

- Start to click on an object (or the empty space) in the list box control
- Change your mind
- While still holding down the mouse button (i.e., before committing your click), drag the mouse pointer outside of the bounds of the control
- Think: *Whew! That was a close call!*

You'll notice that, in Windows, an action never happens until the mouse button is *released* (often called "MouseUp"). If this wasn't supported, there would be no way for the user to bail out early of an action, which is a critical feature of any user interface.

Comment: I agree with you, but we are talking about programming and of course a programmer cannot predict a user's mind completely.But need a solution.

Comment: This is a standard Windows design practice. You'll see it all over the operating system and other compliant programs. It doesn't require any mind-reading whatsoever. Trying to hack around this important UI characteristic is just going to get you a lot of angry customers and result in a lot of unmaintainable code.

Answer (score 0):

There are some feasible options.
In parent dialog, MouseUp Handler function can use for this.

```
afx_msg void OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
```

By using point, you can check whether mouse releasing is occured CListCtrl.
If it is, you just disable the button.

Also, WindowFromPoint can be another option.

```
static CWnd* PASCAL WindowFromPoint(POINT point);
```

In such as a OnMouseMove, if you use this function, you can check the window is pointed by mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a LVN_ITEMCHANGED handler, and in that handler disable the button as soon as the [selected item count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sdaafak%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is zero.